# Google Chrome reopens tabs when tray icon is used. How to disable?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, session

Since recent update of Google Chrome to version 19.0.1084.52 m it remembers last session when windows is closed and reopens them when I start it again. I have Background apps option enabled and have a Google Chrome tray icon. When I exit by right clicking on the tray icon and selecting Exit option, then tabs are lost.

Is there a way to make Google Chrome forget the session when closing the window? I'd like to see New Tab page instead of some old tabs that I don't need anymore (that is why I close them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is gone on it's own. I presume the Chrome Team in Google has fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make Google Chrome forget the session when closing the window? I'd like to see New Tab page instead of some old tabs that I don't need anymore (that is why I close them)?

1. Go to `chrome://chrome/settings/`.
2. In `On startup`, select `Open the New Tab page`.

Comment: It is set to this value, but still reopens old tabs. I think this is because I am using Background apps.